# Integrating Spellchecker into Tinymce Not working

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce, spell-checking

In my application I used tinymce editor for textareas.

I want to integrate a spellchecker for that so I downloaded the plugin for spell checker and put it into the plugin folder.

Next I changed the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "advlink,paste,spellchecker",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,separator,forecolor,strikethrough,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright, justifyfull,bullist,numlist,undo,redo,link,unlink",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "spellchecker,cut,copy,paste,pastetext,fontselect,fontsizeselect,code",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",

        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,
        spellchecker_languages : "+English=en,Swedish=sv",

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css : "css/content.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

        // Replace values for the template plugin
        template_replace_values : {
            username : "Some User",
            staffid : "991234"
        }
    });
</script>
```

Now the editor is not showing, only the text area is displayed. When I remove the name spellchecker from plugin then the editor loaded. What is the reason for this?

Is there any version problem here?

This is the version details in tiny_mce_src.js file :

```
    majorVersion : '3',
minorVersion : '1.0.1',
releaseDate : '2008-06-18',
```

Comment: I gave up on tinymce years ago, now I use ckeditor, which works quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate: [TinyMCE 4.0.5 spell check not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626276/tinymce-4-0-5-spell-check-not-working/21173658#21173658)

According to what I've found elsewhere, the spellchecker plugin was powered by Google service - which has been retired. So at this time there does not appear to be an integrated TinyMCE spellchecker solution.

However, you CAN enable the browser's built-in spellchecker by doing the following:

```
tinymce.init({
    browser_spellcheck : true,
});
```

Be sure to remove spellchecker from your toolbar and your plugins list.