# TinyMCE 4.0.5 spell check not working

Tags: tinymce

I am currently using TinyMCE 4.0.5 with jQuery package and noticed that spell check is not working

i am using a simple set up

```
tinymce.init({
         selector: "textarea",
         plugins : "spellchecker",
});
```

With this set up i can see the option 'SpellCheck' under 'Tools' but when i click on 'SpellCheck' it throws an error
'Error: GENERAL'

Also there is an error in the error log 
"File does not exist: PATH/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/spellchecker//

but i can see the following file in the above path 
PATH/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/spellchecker/plugin.min.js

Comment: the double slash is from the error log.

Comment: Yes I thinking that its a project setting being reported in the error log. i.e. PATH/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/spellchecker//plugin.min.js is different from  PATH/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/spellchecker/plugin.min.js hence the error. So find where PATH/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/spellchecker// is being injected into your code and change it too PATH/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/spellchecker/ and see how you go.

Comment: unfortunately, i am unable to find the source

Comment: This might helpful

[TinyMCE 4.0.5 spell check not working][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241992/spellchecker-is-not-working-in-tinymce-4-0-non-json-response/20110417#20110417

Answer (score 36):

According to what I've found elsewhere, the spellchecker plugin was powered by Google service - which has been retired. So at this time there does not appear to be an integrated TinyMCE spellchecker solution.

However, you CAN enable the browser's built-in spellchecker by doing the following:

```
tinymce.init({
    browser_spellcheck : true,
});
```

Be sure to remove spellchecker from your toolbar and your plugins list.

Comment: As a note for others who come across this post. If you are in Firefox, you will see misspelled words but when you right click you get TinyMCE's context menu. (IE 11 works okay, I've read) You need to disable TinyMCE's context menu. You do that by adding `contextmenu: false,` to the init code. Also, remove `contextmenu` from the plugins. Works great after that!

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this and solution is even more weird then problem itself: the thing is, that when plugin misses `spellchecker_rpc_url` parameter, it simply queries the same directory he's in, that's why we get

> File does not exist: PATH/tinymce/js/tinymce/plugins/spellchecker/

Set `spellchecker_rpc_url` parameter to your script URL and **this** error message will be gone.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of the tinyMCE PHP speller checker (2.0.6.1) seems to be for tinyMCE 3.x not 4.x. I had the same issue as you when setting up 4.0.12. Even if I set my `spellchecker_rpc_url` to point to rpc.php from the 2.0.6.1 php, it doesn't work because the code doesn't line up with the JSON request being sent by tinyMCE.

There is unreleased work on the tinyMCE spell checker git hub https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce_spellchecker_php
If you download this and use this instead you should have more luck. Beware though, the Google API doesn't exist any more, so you'll have to use enchant or pspell.

There is also a proposed solution to updating the 2.0.6.1 code to work with 4.x on this post http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=6309%29.

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of R&D how to make it work with PHP and details are given below:

1. Download the community version of tinyMCE form the tinyMCE website. In the download directory, there is a folder spellcheck under plugin folder in which there is a file plugin.min.js. Reference to this file needs to add in the client side code.
2. Download the PHP spell check code from the given URL i.e 
   https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/spellchecking/#phpspellcheckercomponent

Host the same on PHP server. And make sure that the enchant option is enabled on PHP server.

You can check the same via phpserverurl/spellchecker/info.php, find the enchant module [to check the enchant option is enabled or not, on PHP server][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBzDm.png

If the file phpserverurl/spellchecker/info.php does not exist, then create a new file there and write the following code:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Client-side code for tinyMCE:

// Scripts reference

tinymce.init
({
        mode: "exact",
        selector: 'textarea',
        height: 540,
        with: 'auto',
        menubar: false,
        toolbar: 'spellchecker | formatselect | bold italic strikethrough forecolor backcolor | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | numlist bullist outdent indent | undo redo | removeformat',
        toolbar_items_size: 'small',
        branding: false, // To disable "Powered by TinyMCE"
        statusbar: false,
        plugins: "spellchecker",
        spellchecker_rpc_url: 'phpserverurl/spellchecker/spellchecker.php', // this is url of php server where spellchecker code is hosted
        spellchecker_languages: 'en'
    });

Click on spellcheck icon when the editor is rendered and it will give you the suggestions to correct the misspelled words.

If your tinyMCE code and spellchecker code is hosted on a different server then add a line of code in the header of spellchecker.php file i.e given below

```
header ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header ("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header ("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
```

In order to resolve the cross-domain request, otherwise, there is no need to add the above line of code.

Thanks.