# I am not able to make spell checker working in angular ui tinymce

Tags: angularjs, tinymce, tinymce-4, rich-text-editor

I am using angular ui tinymce for creating rich text editor. I have added spell cheker tool iin the tool bar using below code -

```
return {
            setup: function (editor) {
                self.$timeout(function () {
                    editor.focus();
                }, 200)
            },
            statusbar: false,
            menubar: false,
            browser_spellcheck: true,
            spellchecker_languages: 'English=en,German=de,Spanish=es',
            resize: false,
            plugins: 'textcolor colorpicker image anchor link lists advlist table paste spellchecker',
            toolbar1: "fontselect fontsizeselect styleselect | strikethrough bold italic | forecolor backcolor | link image ",
            toolbar2: "alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | spellchecker | table  undo redo",
            height: "400px",
        };
```

The spell checker option is coming properly on screen but it is not working.

When i click on spellchecker icon it is giving me below error.

> "The spelling service was not found: (undefined)"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZ5fi.jpg)
could you guys please help me how to make this working. I have also check .php plug in but there is no documentation how to include in angular ui tinymce.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do more than just load the `spellcheck` plugin to get spellchecking to work in TinyMCE. You effectively have 3 options for spellchecking:

1. ***Rely on the browser's spellchecker.***  This is the easiest option as it only requires you to add one item to the TinyMCE init:  https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/spelling/#browser_spellcheck
2. ***Install an open source server side spelling solution*** and connect it to the `spellchecker` plugin that you are loading.  While you are loading the client side `spellchecker` plugin your configuration does not connect it to any server side spelling service.  The basics on this are documented in the TinyMCE documentation at https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/spell-checking/#phpspellcheckercomponent
3. ***Purchase a commercial Spellchecking solution***. The creators of TinyMCE offer a spellchecking service that you can purchase - its called Spell Checker Pro and is offered as both an on premise install and a cloud service.  The basics are documented here: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/spell-checking/#tinymcespellcheckerproplugin

Comment: it looks like @Onkarraj has followed your first option by setting `browser_spellcheck: true`.  I am trying to follow the same setup and am receiving the same error when clicking the spellchecker icon.  I am getting a 404 on the `/js/plugins/spellchecker` resource

Comment: @Stetzon If you are relying on the browser for spelling you don't need to load the spellchecker plugin.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you are using both the option:

1. browser_spellcheck: true,
2. spellchecker under plugins option, for this you need to do some more work and for that, you need to follow the given link:

[TinyMCE 4.0.5 spell check not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626276/tinymce-4-0-5-spell-check-not-working/49747506#49747506)

Thanks